# Finding value in list

Tags: c++, list

This code snippet determines whether an integer is in a list called `engie`.

> return std::find(engie.begin(), engie.end(), find_value) !=
>   engie.end();

Why is it an if statement comparing the iterator to the end of the list? 
I realize the find range is from [first, last)

So for a list containing the integers {1,2,3}, isn't last = 3? 
How does it find `3` if it isn't searched?

`Input iterators to the initial and final positions in a sequence. The range searched is [first,last), which contains all the elements between first and last, including the element pointed by first but not the element pointed by last.`

Comment: Yes, sorry. Forgot to add the tag.

Comment: `[first,last)` means `first` is included, but `last` is not. Note the square and round brackets.

Comment: last is the one past 3.

Answer (score 1):

`std::find(b, e, v)` searches for value `v` in half-open range `[b,e)`, that is, excluding the last position `e`, and returns the first position where `v` is found, or `e` if `v` is not found in the range. So checking

```
std::find(b, e, v) != e
```

means, in words, "*`v` is found in range `[b,e)`*". You may think of `std::find` as

```
template<typename I, typename T>
I find(I b, I e, const T& v)
{
   while (b != e && !(*b == v))
      ++b;
   return b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function 
    `find (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& val)` returns the position of the first match, if there is a match. Else it returns the **last position**. It will search in the range [first, last). This range includes the first element **but not the last**.

Hence in the code snippet when the iterator is not equal to the last element (i.e. engie.end) you get the match and the position of the match is returned.

You can refer [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/)

Comment: You need `[first, last)`, not `[first, last]`.

Answer (score 0):

In the STL list {1,2,3}, end() does not point to 3, it points to one element past 3 or the "end" of the list.  The find function iterates the list, and if the current iterator equals the value you're trying to find it returns the iterator.  If it never finds the value it returns end() because one element past the last element in the list would be end().

Answer (score 0):

The `find` method returns an iterator to the location (if found) or the value `engie.end()`.

The comparison is simply converting the return value to true if found, false otherwise